# Редактирование кода сниппета с мобильных телефонов

Tags: дефект, сниппеты, мобильная-версия

Заранее приношу извинения, вопрос задавался не раз.

Собственно сабж. В мобильной версии сайта на страницах вопросов/ответов сниппеты полностью отсутствуют. Если в браузере смартфона поставить галочку *desktop-версия*, сниппеты появляются. С некоторыми оговорками вроде почти неработающего скролла, результаты работы кода сниппета показываются и работают. Редактируя вопрос/ответ, можно запускать сниппет из пред-просмотра. Тем самым можно хоть как-то проверить правильность кода в сниппете до публикации (единственный минус, по нажатию кнопки *выполнить код* страница скроллится в самый верх и её приходится скроллить до сниппета снова). Если размера фрейма в сниппете недостаточно, можно воспользоваться ссылкой *развернуть фрагмент*, которая отобразит результат работы кода на весь экран.

Нажав на ссылку редактирования кода под сниппетом, получаем сообщение *The snippet editor does not support touch devices*. Если честно, эта фраза, выражаясь мягко вводит в заблуждение, что у посетителя ресурса может сложиться впечатление, якобы редактор кода не работает на тач-девайсах. - Это не правда. Редактор кода можно запустить комбинацией клавиш `Ctrl+M` и он отлично работает на моём старом смартфоне, да и скорее всего работает на всех смартфонах последних лет 5-6. Но комбинацией `Ctrl+M` можно запустить, как бы, редактор создания нового сниппета. А иногда очень хочется отредактировать уже введённый код.

Собственно, возможно ли как-то обойти эту проверку на наличие тач-скрина в смартфоне, или может есть другая комбинация клавиш помимо `Ctrl+M`?

Comment: Если вопрос «задавался не раз», стоит добавить ссылок, как мне кажется. Я вот заводил давненько смежный [баг](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/303986/339911) на MSE.

Comment: В ту же копилку можно бросить то, что в мобильной версии, при редактировании комментария, не показывает подсказку автора если набрать @

Answer (score 1):

Решил задачу, написав пользовательский скрипт из одной строки кода:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Open StackOverflow snippet editor on touch devices
// @include     https://stackoverflow.com/*
// @include     https://*.stackexchange.com/*
// @include     https://*.stackoverflow.com/*
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==
$('a.edit-snippet').on('touchend', e => (e.target.click(), false));
```

Скрипт отменяет делегирование события `touchend` на ссылках редактирования сниппетов. И за одно кликает по ссылке для открытия редактора.

Вроде отлично работает на любых смартфонах. Жаль, с каждым годом пользовательские скрипты поддерживаются все меньшим количеством мобильных браузеров.